# Application of Implicit Function Thm

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem**

Let $f_{1},f_{2}$: $R^{2}\rightarrow R$ of class $C^2$. Consider the zero sets $Z_{1}, Z_{2}$ (of $f_{1},f_{2}$ respectively) ie $Z_{i}=\{(x,y) | f_{i}(x,y)=0\}$. Assume $\nabla f_{i}(x,y) \neq 0$ if $(x,y)\in Z_{i}$, and there exists a function $\lambda: R^2 \rightarrow R$ such that $\nabla f_{1}(x,y)=\lambda(x,y)\nabla f_{2}(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in R^2$. Assume the intersection of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ is non-empty.

Prove that $Z_1 \cap Z_2$ contains infinitely many points.

**Idea**

So the gradients are parallel, and since the intersection in non-empty the functions share at least a point on the level curves.

WOLG since $\nabla f_{i} \neq 0$ let $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y} \neq 0$ so by implicit function thm we can write (for some neighbor hood small enough) that $f_{i}(x,y)=f_{i}(x,g(x))$ for $x \in Z_{i}$.

I then went down the path of first order approximation, since they are both differentiable. Let $x_0 \in Z_1 \cap Z_2$ then since $f_{i}(x_0)=0$

$f_{1}(h)=\nabla f_{1} (x_0)h$

$f_{2}(h)=\nabla f_{2} (x_0)h=\lambda \nabla f_{1}(x_0)h$

This seems like a dead end though. I thought maybe if one of the partials was zero (and since they are related by lambda) that the derivative matrix would have a determinant of zero, thus the function wouldn't be invertible. Would this prove they aren't 1-1? Not sure where to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbf F(x, y) = (-v, u)$ where $\nabla f_1(x, y) = (u, v)$, i.e., rotate the gradient 90 degrees counterclockwise.

Now find an integral curve for the vector field $\mathbf F$, say, $\gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to \mathbb R^2$, so that $\gamma'(t) = \mathbf F(\gamma(t))$, with $\gamma(0)$ being any point at which $f_1 = 0$.

What's $f_1(\gamma(t))$ look like? I claim it's constant, indeed, everywhere zero.

For if we let
$$
h(t) = f_1(\gamma(t)),
$$
then 
\begin{align}
h'(t) &= \nabla f_1 (\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) \\
 &= \nabla f_1 (\gamma(t)) \cdot \mathbf F(\gamma(t))
\end{align}
and these last two are orthogonal by construction.

The same reasoning shows that $f_2$ is constant on $\gamma$, and hence that $f_1 = f_2$ along the entire image of $\gamma$. Since $\gamma$ is continuous and nonconstant on an open interval, this image contains infinitely many points.

I know there's no application of the IFT here, and if the problem required that, I apologize. I've also used the existence of solutions of differential equations, which may not be something you've proved yet...if that's a problem, again I apologize.